# Tooltips in stacked Altair/Vega-Lite chart disappear when using interval selections

Tags: python, data-visualization, vega-lite, altair

The Altair example gallery contains [a nice example](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/blob/master/altair/examples/interval_selection.py) of how to use interval selections to create two plots where one allows you to define the scale of the other. I have been trying to add tooltips to both parts of the stacked chart by defining the tooltips as part of the base:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.sp500.url

brush = alt.selection(type='interval', encodings=['x'])

base = alt.Chart(source).mark_area().encode(
    x = 'date:T',
    y = 'price:Q',
    tooltip = 'price:Q'
).properties(
    width=600,
    height=200
)

upper = base

lower = base.properties(
    height=60
).add_selection(brush)

upper & lower
```

Doing so, the tooltips work as expected on `lower` but not at all on `upper`.

[image]

If, however, I remove the `.add_selection(brush)` from `lower`, the tooltips also work on `upper` (which was unchanged), but that of course defeats the purpose of the example. I can also make the tooltips work on `upper` by marking it as interactive, but again, that ruins what's nice about the example. Changing the definition of `upper` to `upper = base.encode(tooltip='price:Q')` does nothing.

> How would I define the tooltip target in a way that makes tooltips show up on both `upper` and `lower`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that the tooltips stop working is probably a bug, and it would be worth filing a [Vega-Lite bug report](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/new?labels=Bug+%3Abug%3A&template=Bug_report.md)

It appears you can work around this by adding a second empty selection to the upper chart:

```
upper = base.add_selection(alt.selection_single())
```

You can view the interactive result [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEDGD2B2AzAlgc0gLjMSA3ZApgO6bYwIAuy8ArrDQM4DqyAJhQBakAsADLwBooceFVr0GACQJoOFUgGZ+AX2UDwUXCOgBDeVgDaGiKAhmoAWx0AnANalINgjsjrzESAXhxW1dFlN3DwpYWAAbKgAHUhwKAE9IggcARxodUWQKPWRcJKFIFAIw1gdI62RoJLVjd0gADxjIeMSHCgILSNhrHTDXKELih1Y9KrcgqDjG5qSsSFT0qiyqXL6CwkHZsoqqmohqoMgOGVQ5UgAmfjHzSAYigmgqBEbbsPuQ634FKYSZqAY-V6QVRXMyQIhsTikABs-Bq+zMgWuVjsDicLhBHi8Pj8MV2oJC4Si3xas3mGSWOTy-XWJU25UqQIxoIaASaP1a7U63V6+QGtKgwzajLxHkmrOmKTS5OyK15NNK9J2QXh1yOsn0YBhTJudweyCerJeby6-DOxN+kGobWsuB6qyxsF88FQDFIBnqkAAusC8WCIVwsDDeHCNJ6xpBBS5WTRrL1ZnIKJEGBgAPQp3KoHQAOlQmQ4NAARln9emCJmALSR24UBgpyMphiRACs-Cz0AYuGFHgAJAxoEcrA4E0nU6XMzm84Xi7AG-32joxzpy2FMgR09ws7ws2cswArBhPEDKIA).

Comment: Thanks; this workaround should do the job in my case. I've added a [bug report](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/6003).

Comment: Actually, this *almost* works, but I noticed that when hovering the data in the _actual selection_ in the bottom chart, the tooltip still won't work.